# The 50 value problems in TAoCP

Tags: research

This is just a question for fun and specifically for those who have read the reference pervasively.

I have been reading the work of Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming and struggling and having a lot of fun with its exercises. I was very impressed that Fermat's Last Theorem had a difficulty of 45 in Knuth's difficulty scale.

I was wondering, if anyone of you have seen exercises with rank ≥50.

Perhaps a more interesting question, what is the current status of such problems nowadays!?

Comment: I think this is too broad in its current form. You seem to ask for many things: there are presumably several hard problems, each with their current status, whatever that might mean exactly.

Comment: @Juho I don't think that a question about the ratings of exercises within a particular series of books is overly broad.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think I still disagree. If you already know there is a problem with difficulty 45, why not look at the book(s) yourself, and find out exactly the set of problems that are interesting, and ask specific questions about those problems? Well, let's let the community decide.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, my immediate reaction is: "Does the problem have any exercise with rank ≥50?" is not too broad, but it is likely off-topic: it is a question about a book, not a question about computer science.  "What is the current status of all exercises with rank ≥50?" is too broad.   Either way, the question doesn't seem suitable.  Including both of these questions in the post seems to make it either too broad or off-topic or both.  But that's just my instinctual reaction.  Community votes would be appropriate here.

Comment: It is a question from a book about computer science, and the book offers open problems in the topic. Besides, there are not too many exercises with such ranking, so the scope could no be too large, and a few sentences about each one of them would be appreciated. The question is interesting for someone outside the temple of being computer scientist

Comment: @D.W. I would recommend you to try an exercise with ranking ~40 and then decide if a more difficult problem it's research problem or not. There are many topics in the series, so feel free to pick the best that suits you.

Comment: @D.W. I was assuming there'd only be a few 50-rated exercises. Anyway, not something I feel strongly about.

Comment: @user2820579 I don't see how somebody comparing a 40-ranked exercise with a research problem would help answer your question. And if you're envisioning multiple answers, each addressing one or two exercises, then I agree with the others: that looks too broad.

Comment: user2820579, [We expect you to make a significant effort before asking](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  So why don't you look through the book yourself and compile a list of all exercises with rank ≥50?  This isn't a place to outsource a task like that.  (And then once you've done that, you could ask a specific question about the current status of one of those.)

Comment: @D.W. I would expect for you to make a significant effort answering as well, and of course to read the question with care (__question just for fun__). I already put an example in context just for reference of what is the hardness of the research problems proposed. The spirit of the question was to know in a broader sense what are unsolved topics in computer science with some pointers of what has been done in the field. It doesn't harm to have a compiled list of unsolved problems from an especific reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, "what are unsolved topics in computer science?" would be too broad for this site.  I realize this might be somewhat counter-intuitive if you're not familiar with this site.  While we don't necessarily have a strict policy for list questions, there is a 
[general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). 
Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and
[this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion.  If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Comment: I will survey through your suggestions. Thanks for the reply and your interest in it.

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem was 50 in early editions, until some student hired for proofreading found a proof that was too short to fit on the margins of the book. Sorry, until Wiles proved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knuth's scale goes up to 50 (for "unsolved research problems"). Note that the scale is meant to be (roughly) logarithmic, i.e., adding 10 to the number multiplies the work required by a factor, with 50 meaning some so ridiculously large amount of work to be done that it can be taken practically as "infinite".

Fermat's Last Theorem used to be 50 as an example in the preface, with Wiles' proof it is now "just" extremely hard, i.e., it got demoted to 45 in later editions.

So the answer to the question is "no". By *definition* 50 is the highest value on the scale.

Comment: The question asks if there's something "with rank ≥50". That's not excluded by definition of the scale going up to 50.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, by Knuth's *definition* the top is 50. It used to be the rating of Fermat's Last Theorem for a reason.

Comment: OK, I'm confused. You say, "The answer to the question is 'no'." I assume the question you mean is whether there's an exercise with rating greater than **or equal to** 50. Knuth's definition is that every question has a question less than **or equal to** 50. So Knuth's definition alone does not imply that the answer is no: a question rated exactly 50 is possible.

Comment: I think maybe an $e^\frac{1}{50-x}$ would be a better rough estimation then.